# Not able to execute callbacks in module.exports object using Node-Cron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

So I am using a module called [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to execute a chain of functions every night.

My function is located in another file.  I have added `required` that file in my app.js where the node-cron Object is located.  That Object looks like this

```
var job = new CronJob('00 51 17 * * 0-6', savantJS.getTracksFromSavants, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

This will execute the `getTracksFromSavants` function in my savantJS file at 5:51pm LA time just fine.  However the problem occurs when I try to have callback functions in my savantJS file.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  getTracksFromSavants: function(){
    //do stuff here with arr
    if(stuff happens here){
      this.doNextFunction(arr)
    }
  },
  doNextFunction: function(arr){
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

This executes the `getTracksFromSavants` function fine, but once it gets to the `if` it says that `doNextFunction` is not defined.

On the flip side, if I write my Cron like this:

```
    var job = new CronJob('00 51 17 * * 0-6', savantJS.getTracksFromSavants(), null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

It executes the callbacks in `getTracksFromSavants()` fine.  However the issue is that when I use the `()` in the CronJob object it executes that function every time the server is started when it should only be executing it at 5:51pm.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you check what is `this` before calling `doNextFunction`?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran `this` is referring to the module.exports object...I think. I can confirm this because the callbacks all work fine when I set the function to be executed in the cron to `savantJS.getTracksFromSavants()` as the callback to `this.doNextFunction` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
  f: function() {
    return this;
  }
}

obj.f() // returns obj
var ff = obj.f;
ff(); // does not return obj - `ff` does not know the function came from `f`.
ff = ff.bind(obj);
ff(); // returns obj again
```

In JavaScript, calling a method using a dot notation will set `this`. calling a method without the dot does not. When you pass `savantJS.getTracksFromSavants` into a function, it becomes some parameter; when that parameter gets called, it does not know it has any connection to `savantJS`. Unless you bind the receiver to it.

Thus, you want to wrap your method call inside a normal function (that does not depend on being invoked as a method):

```
var job = new CronJob('00 51 17 * * 0-6', function() {
  savantJS.getTracksFromSavants();
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Or you can bind the function to a receiver (which basically does the same thing):

```
var job = new CronJob('00 51 17 * * 0-6', 
  savantJS.getTracksFromSavants.bind(savantJS),
  null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining! That makes sense and it works as intended :).